# procedure oracle inner join

Tags: oracle11g, inner-join

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Proc_factura 
IS 
BEGIN 
    SELECT venta.rut_cliente, 
           cliente.nombre, 
           cliente.direccion, 
           cliente.telefono, 
           venta.fecha, 
           vendedor.nombre, 
           venta.codigo_vehiculo, 
           vehiculo_nuevo.marca, 
           vehiculo_nuevo.modelo, 
           vehiculo_nuevo.cilindrada, 
           vehiculo_nuevo.precio * 1.19 
    FROM   venta 
           inner join cliente 
                   ON venta.rut_cliente = cliente.rut 
           inner join vendedor 
                   ON vendedor.rut = venta.rut_vendedor 
           inner join vehiculo_nuevo 
                   ON venta.codigo_vehiculo = vehiculo_nuevo.codigo; 
END;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to `SELECT` those values `INTO` something in order to make it compile (at least). Will it work, that's another question.